# Gitlab CI shell executor can't run docker-compose

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Hi Im using shell executor in my gitlab-ci on gitlab runner installed on a host as systemctl application. I'm getting error while run docker-compose.
I did add priveledges to gitlab-runner using:
`usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner`

My error:
`error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/json?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.config-hash%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.project% dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.10.0.2:53: no such host`

My Gitlab CI pipeline:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
deploy:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell_executor
  script:
    - pwd
    - docker-compose ps 
    - docker-compose up -d
```

Config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "shell_executor"
  url = "https://xxxxxxxx"
  id = 1
  token = "xxxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-12-21T13:58:41Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
```

I tried to use docker executor, then ssh to the host and run docker-compose up. That's working, but I would prefer using shell executor installed on host.

Comment: `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/` there is no docker at host named `docker`. You are mounting docker from host `volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"`. Just use empty DOCKER_HOSt or point it to /var/run/docker.sock. Also, you are using shell executor, so I would guess volumes is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/

There is no docker at host named docker. You get it, *when* you are running in docker executor and in addition to your docker another `services: docker:dind` is started, and that another docker container is named `docker` and is running docker-in-docker and exposing that docker on port 2375..

You are mounting docker from host volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock". But you are using shell executor, so the `volumes` doesn't mean anything.

Just remove DOCKER_HOST, you are running on host, it will point to /var/run/docker.sock by default.